# CSS fixed navbar apply new style if a certain element is reached with scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a fixed bootstrap navnar, which is transparent.

Now I want this style to change when I scroll and the navbar reaches a certain element with the id `services`.

I tried working with heigths, but somehow the values do not update when I scroll.
I would like the navbar to be transparent at beginning and if it reaches the `service` container it should become colored.

What I tryed:

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
    var service_height = $('#service').outerHeight()
    var navbar_height = $('.mynavbar').outerHeight()
    console.log("service" + service_height);
    console.log("navbar" + navbar_height);
    // we round here to reduce a little workload
    //stop = Math.round($(window).scrollTop());
    if (navbar_height >= service_height) {
        $('.mynavbar').addClass('past-main');
    } else {
        $('.mynavbar').removeClass('past-main');
   }

});
```

What I want:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is weird, you are trying to compare height of the navbar and height of the services section and based on that add or remove class.

You should get the current top position of the services section relative to the document and compare it to the current scroll position.

You can use [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) and [`scrollTop()`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) jQuery functions for that.

```
var trigger;

$(window).scroll(function() {

  trigger = $('#section-3').offset().top - $('.navbar').height();

  if ($(this).scrollTop() > trigger) {
    $('.navbar').addClass('bg');
  } else {
    $('.navbar').removeClass('bg');
  }

});
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/zoLvQL)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Bootstrap [ScrollSpy component](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy) and set the scroll position to the top of "services". Use CSS to define the navbar styles for `.affix-top` and `.affix`.

```
   /* navbar style once affixed to the page */ 
   .affix {
         background-color: black;   
    }

    @media (min-width:768px) {
        .affix-top {
          /* navbar style at top */
          background-color:transparent;
          border-color:transparent;
          padding: 15px; 
        }
    }
```

**Demo:**
http://www.codeply.com/go/JNy8BtYSem